# $anchorScroll directive not working in IE 11

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

My directive works in Chrome but not IE, as far as I can tell the goTo function isn't getting called, however the url updates to http://localhost:3000/#top. Please help. See my code below.

Directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.widgets').directive('mmScrollTo', mmScrollTo);

    mmScrollTo.$inject = ['$anchorScroll', '$location', '$window'];

    function mmScrollTo ($anchorScroll, $location, $window) {
        // Usage:
        //     <directive1></directive1>
        // Creates:
        // 
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'EA',
            bindToController: true,
            controller: ScrollToController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'app/widgets/mm-scroll-to.html'
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                if (this.pageYOffset > 100) {
                    scope.display  = true;
                } else {
                    scope.display  = false;
                }
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }

        /* @ngInject */
        function ScrollToController ($anchorScroll, $location) {
            var vm = this;   
            vm.goto = function(x) {
                var newHash = x;
                if($location.hash() !== newHash) {
                    $location.hash(x);
                } else {
                    $anchorScroll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
})()
```

Template:

```
<div ng-show="display" class="scroll-to animate-show">
<a href="" ng-click="vm.goto('top')"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up fa-2x"></i></a>
```

HTML:
    Content

Answer (score 0):

I changed the template to adding the hash in the href attribute and it works now.

```
    <div ng-show="display" class="scroll-to animate-show">
<a href="#" ng-click="vm.goto('top')"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up fa-2x"></i></a>
```